# Read live digital stream via usb in Android

Tags: android, usb, video-capture

I have a digital stream as output from TV capture card which takes AV port (audio-video) input and outputs via usb port.

I have an android box which takes this TV capture card usb out as input.

How do I read this continuous video stream from usb and display it in android video view or similar?